# Issue in subString from my String in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

i have requirement of get all possible substring from a string. I have done below solution for the same But i am getting crash when loop is running for second time(i =1 and j=4).can somebody help me what is issue on below code.

```
 NSString *str = @"test";
    NSUInteger length = str.length;
    for (int i = 0 ;i<length;i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j <= length; j++){
            NSString *myStr = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, j)];
            NSLog(@"%@",myStr);
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, 'i' denote the starting location of the string and 'j' denote the length you want. If i + j beyond the length of the string , the program will crash. You should read the document of the method carefully when you come across such problem. I have modified your code as below:

```
NSString *str = @"test";
NSUInteger length = str.length;
for (int i = 0 ;i < length;i++){
    for (NSUInteger j = length - i; j > 0; j--){
        NSString *myStr = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, j)];
        NSLog(@"%@",myStr);
    }
}
```